# How to use git-svn when SVN repository really contains multiple "repositories"?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Supposed I have an umbrella SVN repo, "CompanyName". Within this repo, there are many projects, "Project1", "Project2", ..., "ProjectN". E.g. the SVN repo houses multiple projects instead of a single repo per project. I want to "move" Project1 to Git, so I tried to do this:

```
git svn clone --no-metadata --authors-file=users.txt --prefix=origin/ --trunk=Trunk --branches=Branches svn+ssh://me@svn.dev.companyname.biz/svn/CompanyName/Internal/Project1/
```

To which, git-svn responds:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/Projects/CompanyName/Internal/Project1/.git/
Using higher level of URL: svn+ssh://me@svn.dev.companyname.biz/svn/CompanyName/Internal/Project1 => svn+ssh://me@svn.dev.companyname.biz/svn/CompanyName
```

Note that git has correctly moved up to the root of the repository, although I want it to focus on the path I specified. Moving into `Project1`, running `git branch -r` gives me no output, so this did not appear to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by using the `--no-minimize-url` option to `git svn`:

```
git svn clone --no-metadata --authors-file=users.txt --prefix=origin/ --trunk=Trunk --branches=Branches --no-minimize-url svn+ssh://me@svn.dev.companyname.biz/svn/CompanyName/Internal/Project1/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error.  I resolved it by using --no-minimize-url

This is my full URL , the -r specifies from which version I want to take and after that I did  git snv rebase

git svn clone -r 15846 svnurl -T trunk -A ../authors.txt gitreponame --no-minimize-url